# Force tt_news to always retrieve new posts

Tags: typo3, tt-news

Is it possible to force tt_news to always retrieve new posts?

I have a plugin that allows user to post news in front-end.
The news are inserted into the tt_news table and the user redirected to the page where the news are listed.
But the latest news that the user posted is not visible.

I have to wait a couple of seconds and then reload the page. This really destroys the site usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions:

1) set the page to "do not cache" (edit page properties). But this will prevent indexed_search to search that site, which is probably ok.

2) add a hook, which clears the cache for that site (have a look at t_c_emain.html#a339ac0da0377744f512bf790e79f5563">http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/classt3lib_t_c_emain.html#a339ac0da0377744f512bf790e79f5563) not that easy

3) add &no_cache=1 and set cache-time of the page to a few minutes (so the page will be indexed via indexed_search)

4) Write an AJAX Script (eID) which request the newest News Records which are not show yet.

I think, it depends on your needs which way to go. 1) is the quickest from developer point of view, but the worst in the performance view. 2) is harder for the developer, perhaps better for the performance, 3) something in between. 4) is perhaps a better solution if there are a lot of users

Comment: Thanks. I think #3 is the way to go. I'll try that and get back later today.